# Call a C/C++ program with WiringPi in Python - Raspberry

Tags: python, c, callback, raspberry-pi3, encoder

I am creating a mobile robot at my work using a Raspberry 3b+ as microcontroller. To determine the robot displacement I am using a motor with encoder sensors.

The problem is: I need to read the Encoder channel changing to count the pulses and also determine the direction. To do this I was using a callback to read the pulses edge, but the callback it is not fast enough to get all the edges and I lost information because of that.

A solution that I could think it was to use a C program using the WiringPi library to read the encoder, I tested it and it worked. Now I need to use this C program in my Python project.

Any idea in how I can do that?

Comment: Did look search for `popen`? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Will my program be able to pass data between processes? Because I need to read te encoder count in my main program.

Comment: Yep, it's the idea of popen: read the output of a process like a file